# Dumb question but I find it interesting

Tags: vector-spaces

I was playing around with random functions in Geogebra when I've made this by total randomness
[f(x)=(cos(x)/sin(x),sin(x))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcuFa.png)

so, if I am guessing right, this function calculates in a 2d space some points defined by $\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} , \sin x\right)$. But here is not yet the actual question.

After I've been seing this, I wondered "that ressemble to a sort of artistic representation of a black hole! can I port it in a 3d space with a variation on y axis?"
and so I did this.

[A(x,y) = ( cos(x)/sin(x), cos(y)/sin(y), sin(x)*sin(y) )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqS70.png)

I've just added a second parameter by copying the first and replacing it by `y` and then on the last parameter, I've added `sin(y)` to create this function $A(x,y) = \left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}, \frac{\cos y}{\sin y}, \sin x \times \sin y \right)$

so here comes the real question:

I've been following a basic logic to add an extra parameter to make the function react to the `y` axis. so "I want to take z as a third parameter. I'll do the same and add a third parameter defined by `cos(z)/sin(z)` and on the last make it like `sin(x)*sin(y)*sin(z)`." (I've passed through different steps before figuring out that I can use 4d space for this. I'll put them in a comment bellow.) But I don't have a 4d space calculator working like Geogebra, how can I see the result?

So can somebody help me rendering this calculation?

here is the final equation:
$f(x,y,z) = \left( \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}, \frac{\cos y}{\sin y}, \frac{\cos z}{\sin z}, \sin x \times \sin y \times \sin z \right)$

Also if you see errors or miss thinking, please report it to me, I'm in art high-school and I haven't been in a science course since 1 year now.

thank you for your time,

Louis

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: You realize, do you not, that "cos(x)/sin(x)" is just "cot(x)"?

Comment: I haven't learned in class that cos(x)/sin(x) is cot(x). I stoped learning mathematical stuff after my terminal bac diploma (French school level, I was in sti2d so it was computer oriented studies).

Comment: `Please use MathJax to format. – Saad`

I did the change

Comment: The fact that "cos(x)/sin(x)" is just "cot(x)" is unimportant. The important thing is to understand exactly what the question is about. @Louis : your $f(x,y,z)$ takes as input 3 numbers $(x,y,z)$ and gives 3 numbers $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. This is what is called a "vector field". So if you want to plot it you have to use little arrows: at every point $(x,y,z)$ you have a little arrow in the direction $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$. I'm not sure why you are interested in plotting such a thing but you can try with Wolphram Alpha: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot3D.html

Comment: by little arrow, do you mean a vector pointing in a direction?

Comment: But thanks, I'll try it ! @mrcntn

Comment: Yes, arrows = vectors in a direction. Of course your field is strange, it has 4 numbers as output. You can only plot stuff with 3 output numbers. I' m not sure I understand why you want to do this but in any case you will be forced to suppress a output number in your definition of $f$.

Comment: okay ! thanks for your help !

Comment: I think I might want to do it because of quarantine

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps i'v come through

first I tried to change the last parameter of the point by this `cos(x)/sin(x)`

so it gave me this function:

$f(x,y,z) = \left (\frac{cos x}{\sin x},\frac{cos y}{\sin y},\frac{cos z}{\sin z} \right)$

unfortunately, geogebra does not want to calculate it.
so I've tried making separate 3d functions taking only 2 axis as a time and then multiply them:

$A(x,y)   = \left (\frac{\cos x}{sin x}, \frac{\cos y}{sin y}, \sin x \times \sin y \right)$

$B(x,z)   = \left (\frac{\cos x}{sin x}, \sin x\times \sin z, \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} \right)$

$C(y,z)   = \left( \sin y \times \sin z, \frac{\cos y}{sin y}, \frac{\cos z}{sin z} \right)$

$D(x,y,z)   = A(x,y) \times B(x,z) \times C(y,z)$

no need to say that it doesn't worked either.

so I said to my self, ok I'll make a new function where I multiply every parameter of the point defined in my A,B and C functions to make a new one defining a 3d point in space like I've done lately.

so I did this function:

$A(x,y)   = \left (\frac{\cos x}{sin x}, \frac{\cos y}{sin y}, \sin x \times \sin y \right)$

$B(x,z)   = \left (\frac{\cos x}{sin x}, \sin x\times \sin z, \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} \right)$

$C(y,z)   = \left( \sin y \times \sin z, \frac{\cos y}{sin y}, \frac{\cos z}{sin z} \right)$

$a = A(x,y) \to x \times B(x,z) \to x \times C(y,z) \to x$

$b = A(x,y) \to y \times B(x,z) \to y \times C(y,z) \to y$

$c = A(x,y) \to z \times B(x,z) \to z \times C(y,z) \to z$

$D(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$

$= \left( \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \times \frac{\cos y}{\sin y} \times \left( \sin x \times \sin y \right),
\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \times \left( \sin x \times \sin z \right) \times \frac{\cos z}{\sin z},
\left( \sin y \times \sin z \right) \times \frac{\cos y}{\sin y} \times \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} \right) $

so

$D(x,y,z) = \left( \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \times \frac{\cos y}{\sin y} \times \left( \sin x \times \sin y \right),
\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \times \left( \sin x \times \sin z \right) \times \frac{\cos z}{\sin z},
\left( \sin y \times \sin z \right) \times \frac{\cos y}{\sin y} \times \frac{\cos z}{\sin z} \right) $

it didn't worked either.